# jquery multiply 2 textboxs then show the solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiplication

I have this code that is not working. I am trying to multiply 2 textboxs and show the solution, but it doesn't show anything when I click. The code I have so far is this... what can be wrong with the code below?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#AddProduct').click(function() {
        var totalPrice = $('#debt').val() * $('#income').val();
        $('#solution').val() = totalPrice;
    });
</script>

<form name="form" method="post" action="">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="income" id="income" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="debt" id="debt" /></td>
            <td><input type="text"  id="solution"  name="solution" /> </td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After, you add jquery to your page as below

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

you can do the following:

```
$('#AddProduct').click(function() {
var totalPrice = parseInt($('#debt').val(),10) * parseInt($('#income').val(),10);
$('#solution').val(totalPrice);
});
```

You have to tell it you want the `value` of the input you are targeting.
And also, always provide the second argument (radix) to `parseInt`.  It tries to be too clever and autodetect it if not provided and can lead to unexpected results.

Providing `10` assumes you are wanting a base 10 number.

Answer (score 4):

Your jQuery needs to be:

```
$('#AddProduct').click(function() {
   var totalPrice = parseInt($('#debt').val()) * parseInt($('#income').val()); // you can't multiply strings
   $('#solution').val(totalPrice); // This is how you use .val() to set the value.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that you'd set the value of the solution textbox:

```
$('#solution').val(totalPrice);
```

Also, do you actually have an element with an id of 'AddProduct' on your page?

Comment: yes i do in the submit, I was just making my code cleaner and accidently deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalPrice = $('#debt').val() * $('#income').val();
$('#solution').val(totalPrice);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NqaCR/)